# Regex for 1 or 2 digits with one optional decimal place

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, formatter

I'm using: http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/index.html to mask inputs.

I'm looking at "patterns" option and am having trouble writing the regex expression for 1 or 2 digits with an optional decimal place.

Good inputs: 
2.5 
12.5 
.5 
1

Bad inputs: 
.25 
123.5 
1.55

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 17):

```
^\d{0,2}(?:\.\d)?$
```

- `\d{0,2}` = 0-2 digits
- `\.\d` = decimal point followed by 1 digit
- `(?: ... )?` = optional group
- `^` and `$` anchor it to beginning and end

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Em4PCV/1)

Comment: Why isn't is selected ?

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari What isn't selected?

Comment: Oh I meant..why this answer is not selected by OP

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari The OP hasn't logged into SO for over 3 months.

Comment: How do we check that by the way?

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari I clicked on his name to go to his profile. It says "Last seen Jun 22 at 21:42".